# How do I write page number and date outside the border in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have to write the date and page number in an assignment, but it is supposed to be outside the border.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You could:

1. Reduce the top margin, and
2. Put the page number and date into the header.

This will show the page number and date, in the margin above every page.

If you want to have the page number and date show in the margin **below** every page, then instead of reducing the top margin, you should reduce the **bottom** margin, and put the page number and date into the ***"footer"***.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **Insert** tab and there you have the **Header & Footer** section, there you can choose to put preformatted headers and/or footers and you can choose to put in pagenumbers in a variety of styles and places.

Answer (score 0):

Insert > Page Number > Top of page

To get it outside the border:

Page Layout > Page Setup > Layout tab > Borders > Box (or any border) > Options > **UNCLICK Surround Header**.